# JavaScript: Unexpected token while declaring method outside an object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, meteor

I am struggling a lot with a method I want to declare. All I get is an "Unexpected token {". I don't get it, and I am blocked since 2 days. Now, I really need to move on this thing.

Can anyone help me?

Here the meteorpad: [meteorpad.com/pad/6TnXLxumi68Kr6ioA/](http://meteorpad.com/pad/6TnXLxumi68Kr6ioA/).
And here the relevant part:

```
GameFactory = {};    
GameFactory.createGame = function (playersIds) {
  var players = initPlayers(playerIds);

  GameFactory.dealHands(players) ;

  return {
    players: players,
    isRunning: true,
    startedOn: new Date()
  };
};


function initPlayers(playersIds) {
  var o = {};

  playersIds.forEach(function (id) {
    o[id] = {
      playerId: id,
      hand: [],
      target: 0,
      score: 0
    };
  });

  return o;
}

GameFactory.dealHands(players) {
  var card = {value: 'toto'};
  Object.keys(players).forEach(function (id) {
    players[id].hand.push(card);
  });
}
```

Comment: I wonder if you really want to push the same card onto each player's hand. This means that if you change the `value` property on one player's card, it will change on all players' cards. If you want distinct cards for each player, move the `var card` line inside the inner function.

Comment: Yes, thank you for noticing it. It is just a numb test that I used to (try to) debug. There will be no 'toto' in that game! ;) Still thanks for both of you answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
GameFactory.dealHands = function (players) {
  var card = {value: 'toto'};
  Object.keys(players).forEach(function (id) {
    players[id].hand.push(card);
  });
}
```

You were missing the `function` keyword for `GameFactory.dealHands`.

Comment: Rather than acting as a human parser/syntax checker, it would be more helpful if you could guide the OP in how to find such errors, since he can hardly post to SO every time he runs into a syntax error.

Comment: The great thing about StackOverflow is if you have a better answer, then you are welcome to supply it. And, as it appears, you have done so. ;)

Comment: @torazaburo Well I know it wasn't a nice question to stack here.

But I was some kind of desperate. And believe me, I searched a lot on my own to get the answer. The worst of all, is that I DID try T. Cordova answer. I did! (Right after that I read [3 ways to define a JavaScript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) Stoyand's article.)

Thanks anyway for you help guys!

Answer (score 1):

For me, in Chrome devtools, I get the error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

pointing directly to the line

```
GameFactory.dealHands(players) {
```

JSHint reports the error slightly differently

```
line 30, column 31, Missing semicolon
```

going so far as to actually point out the specific character position of the `{`.

It's hard to ask these tools to do much more than that. They can hardly be expected to infer based on the `{` that maybe you wanted to declare a function. Would you prefer an error message such as the following?

> Found a `{` in an odd place; perhaps you were trying to declare a function but omitted the `function` keyword?

Judicious use of tools such as the console and jshint, along with a little common sense, makes it pretty easy to track down these kinds of syntax errors. Your editor can also help; most good ones will highlight such errors. For instance, my editor colors the offending `{` red, and offers the message "Missing ; before statement". What editor are you using and does it do syntax highlighting?